# Edelstein Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

Let $(M,d)$ be a compact metric space and $d(f(x),f(y)) < d(x,y) $ for all $ x\neq y$ Prove that if $f$ is a continuous fuction then there is a unique $x_0 \in M $ such that $f(x_0)=x_0$

I know that since $g(x) = d((f(x),f(y))$ is continuous then a continuous function in a compact space reaches its maximum and minimum. Then by proving that the minimum of $g(x)$ = 0 can I conclude that $x_0$ is a fixed point?

Comment: Use [Banach's fixed point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem).

Comment: If $d(f(x),f(y))<d(x,y)$ for all $x,y$ such that $x\ne y$, then $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Instead, you should consider the minimum of $h(x)=d(x,f(x))$. Whenever $h(x)=0$, $x$ is a fixed point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The map $h:M\to \mathbb R$ defined by $h(x)=d(x,f(x))$ is continuous. To see this, note
$$
d(x,f(x))\le d(x,y)+d(y,f(y))+d(f(y),f(x))<d(x,y)+d(y,f(y))+d(x,y)
$$
so $h(x)-h(y)< 2d(x,y)$. The same logic implies $h(y)-h(x)<2d(x,y)$, and continuity follows.

Let $x^*$ attain the minimum value of $h$. I claim that $h(x^*)=0$. Suppose not; then $d(x,f(x))\neq 0$, so $x\neq f(x)$, implying
$$
h(f(x^*))=d(\,\,f(x^*),f(f(x^*))\,)<d(x^*,f(x^*))=h(x^*),
$$
contradicting the minimality of $h$.

Therefore, $h(x^*)=0$, so $f(x^*)=x^*$. To prove uniqueness, let $x$ and $y$ be two distinct fixed points, and use the contraction property to get a contradiction.